# Six People Party (Proof Check)

Tags: graph-theory

Currently reading "Introduction to Graph Theory" by Douglas B. West. I have my doubts whether the following proof I managed to compose is accurate, or if it could be simplified.

*"Prove that at any party with six people, there are three mutual acquaintances or three mutual strangers."*

**Proof.** Because acquaintance is a symmetric relation, we can model it using a simple graph $G$ under six vertices with a vertex for each person and an edge for each acquainted pair. Let $C=\{\text{Orange, Blue}\}$ where if pair $(u,v)$ are acquainted then edge $uv \in E(G)$ is colored orange, otherwise blue. Since every pair of people is either acquainted or not, then $G$ must be a complete graph.

Now, observe that for any vertex $v \in V(G)$ we have that $|N_G(v)|=5$. There must be at least $|C|+1$ edges incident to $v$ of equal coloring because the size of the neighborhood of $v$ is an odd number. Without loss of generality, consider the figure below and choose some vertex $v \in V(G)$.

[image]

Recall $G$ is a complete graph so there must exist a 3-vertex subset $S \subseteq V(G)$ where all $u\in S$ is adjacent to $v$ and all edges $uv$ are equally colored. Because $|C|<3$ and the induced subgraph $G[S]\cong K_3$ then at least two edges in $G[S]$ must be equally colored.

[image]

If all edges in $G[S]$ are equally colored then all vertices in $S\subseteq V(G)$ are three mutual acquaintances or three mutual strangers. Otherwise, there exist at least one edge $u_iu_j \in E(G[S])$ equally colored as all edges of the form $uv$ inducing a 3-vertex cycle where all vertices are mutually acquainted or mutual strangers. QED.

Comment: Looks fine might want to use the pigeon hole principle to make it rigorous

Comment: This question is sooo standard. At least [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/510792/11619), [a cute application](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1875785/11619), [a beefed up variant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/454455/11619). In other words, duplicate in many way.